# Is there any way to set multiple custom headers in jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am sending authentication request to my server but prior to that I need to set two types of header.
(e.g.Content-Type and Security key). Please let me know how to set these custom headers using jQuery, Ajax.
Also whether it is possible to authenticate user using jQuery, Ajax or do we need to use scripting lang (e.g. PHP, JSP.....)
I have tried following.

```
   url: "https://mysite",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: { 'MYKey': 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST' },
data: JSON.stringify(data),
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    success:function (data) {
    //var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            //alert(data+"");
    console.log(data);
    alert(JSON.stringify(data)+" Success");
       //JSON.parse(t);

    },
    error:function(data){
    //var obj1=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    //var x= JSON.parse("two"+data);
    //alert(obj1.uid+"vinay");
    console.log(data);
    alert(JSON.stringify(data)+" error");
    }
```

Let me know whether this approach works to authenticate over https?

I'm getting following error
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
Regds

Answer (score 0):

Try beforesend

```
$.ajax({
     url: "https://mysite",
     data: JSON.stringify(data),
     type: "POST",
     beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('MYKey', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST');},
     success: function() { alert('Success!); }
  });
```

Comment: I tried this as well but it gives reply like this "readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}